# 2000s animated children’s time travel TV show with ensuring Pompeii's destruction get documented, and saving Benjamin Franklin from poisoning

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

I don’t know what channel this show was on, because I had the DVDs as a child; but I know that I watched it around 2008–2009, so it would have come out a little before then (maybe 2006?).

The plot, as much of it as I remember, is as follows: four teens get sent back in time and are jumping from important location in history to important location in history. One of the episode plot lines deals with Paul Revere, and one of the characters has to hang the lanterns on the Old North Church steeple. I can’t remember if this happens in the same episode, but there's also a plot line where the bad guys (who have been chasing the teens through time) tried to poison Ben Franklin, so that he couldn’t sign the Declaration of Independence. (That was kind of the bad guys' thing—they wanted to stop important events in history from happening.)

In another episode, the teens are sent back to ancient Rome and are sent into this Colosseum-like arena. (I don’t think it was the Colosseum because they were in Pompeii but creative license and all.) I remember in this episode they had to escape the arena and get away from Pompeii before it was destroyed. There was also this Roman citizen named Guy. The group saves him; he ends up being important; and it turns out that the bad guys were trying to kill him so he wouldn't document the eruption of Mount Vesuvius.

If it helps, it was in English. I don’t remember what animation style it was in, however.

Comment: Incidentally, in real life it was Pliny the Younger who wrote about the eruption of Vesuvius in 79 AD. It's the [earliest accurate description](http://www.eyewitnesstohistory.com/pompeii.htm) of a volcanic eruption.

Comment: @InvisibleTrihedron Pliny the Younger's full name was, in fact, "Gaius Plinius Caecilius Secundus."

Comment: @Buzz And Gaius ("Guy") would have been the name that friends would address him as. Very good!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think you're looking for the 2005 cartoon *[Masters of Time](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0460349/)*:

> Uploading themselves by way of a time continuum software, Fire, Nevin, Paul, and Kikko, are suddenly whisked back through the ages on a desperate search for their missing computer professor. Unfortunately, they haven't made the journey alone. An evil Hacker is threatening to change world history. The endurance of each intrepid teen will be tested as they weave in and out of time; facing overwhelming perils and thrilling challenges.

Episode 2 is "Escape from Pompeii". Episode 3 is "Paul Revere's Heroic Ride". The Benjamin Franklin episode is 18, "Seizing the High Seas".

Series found by searching for *paul revere time travel cartoon vesuvius*.

Comment: You got there first by six minutes.

Comment: This is it! It appears I was mixing up which historical figure got poisoned. In “Paul Revere’s Heroic Ride”, The Hacker poisons Paul Revere so that he can’t make the journey by horse. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 8):

This sounds like the (German-produced, but I think always in English) television show *[Adventures:  Masters of Time](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0460349/)*.*

Per IMDB:

> Uploading themselves by way of a time continuum software, Fire, Nevin, Paul, and Kikko, are suddenly whisked back through the ages on a desperate search for their missing computer professor. Unfortunately, they haven't made the journey alone. An evil Hacker is threatening to change world history. The endurance of each intrepid teen will be tested as they weave in and out of time; facing overwhelming perils and thrilling challenges.

It had an unusual animation style, so it may not be surprising that you could not remember what style the animation had.

Here is the Pompeii episode.

*Not to be confused with a number of other works with "Masters of Time" in their titles.